# JQuery toggleClass - ajax call breaks event

Tags: jquery

Scenario:

- Simple open close toggleClass on a link (adds class="selected") - opens a div panel
- panel contains a Calendar with links - all works fine
- Calendar has 'next' and 'prev' month linkss - clicking one loads in the chosen month via ajax

Clicking a link within the Calendar simply reloads page, and panel is closed agin - which is ok (ie the 'selected toggle class is removed)

Clicking the months invokes the ajax, but also removed the selected toggle class, so the panel closes

Attempted remedies:
When clicking a next/prev link, adding another class to the link container to force it to stay open - this works but means that the initial toggle selected class is dropped - so the container is then in a 'wrong' state - in that it ought to be selected but isn't but is still open - so it's now out of 'sync'

Bit hard to replicate - tried adding to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/topiman/ZJMKD/3/

---

```
//Show Hide toggle
$('#showhide').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  $('#pickdate').removeClass('stayopen');
  $('.showhide').slideToggle('fast');
  return false;
});

//calendar date toggle
$('.date-prev a').click(function () {
  $('#pickdate').addClass('stayopen');
  return false;
});
```

---

but there it works fine - so it's the Ajaxing action which breaks it / I can't replicate in there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show your ajax call? since you presume that to be the problem

Comment: the calender date toggle function should be called after every ajax call,since new elements will be added through ajax and the function should be available to all the elements of class .date-prev+

Comment: @Bhadra he could use `$('body').on('click','.date-prev a',function(){})` which would work with newly created elements

Comment: hi - thanks for the replies - I can't add my ajax call into fiddle - don't know how (sorry) - it comes from the Drupal calendar module though

Comment: So the problem is the panel closes when you click next/prev month? Is that correct? In your fiddle, the panel actually stays open...